# Error opening connection by sqlite in pycharm

Tags: python, sqlite

When I want to run my database in PyCharm I get this error: *Error opening connection*. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: The error message tells you you have the wrong user id  password

Comment: Yes, just like @Tarik said.. your password and user id combination might not be correct. If you think this is not your case then try to describe your situation in more detail.

Comment: yes but i have just started learning python and i am an Amateur in SQlite. i don't know what's the user & id..  I didn't set theme. if you know how i can change theme please comment here .thanks.